# Сложносочинённое предложение с ПСС или простое с однородными членами?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, ссп

> Я **увидела** кучу огоньков(,) и **решила** разглядеть их поближе.

Это сложносочинённое предложение с причинно-следственной связью или простое с однородными членами?

И ещё. Нужна ли запятая?

Comment: Что такое ПСС??

Comment: @М_Г Там было "с причинно-следственной связью", но shampar отредактировал(а), видимо, для того, чтобы короче было.

Comment: Спасибо, я дополнил вопрос для ясности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Я увидела кучу огоньков и решила разглядеть их поближе.** Это простое предложение, осложненное однородными сказуемыми.

Запятая не ставится, пауза при чтении отсутствует.

Для примера рассмотрим предложение,  которое, как мне кажется, **можно считать сложным.**

**Он увидел кучу огоньков и долго присматривался к ним издалека, и вдруг решился подойти поближе.**

Здесь можно сделать паузу и поставить запятую.

Сказуемые в таких предложениях имеют разные видовые формы, а также могут быть дифференцированы  наречиями со значением времени.

Всё это называют коммуникативной **расчлененностью и самостоятельностью** входящих в предложение частей.

Answer (score 0):

Такие предложения обычно классифицируют как **простые с однородными сказуемыми**. Нигде толком не описано, почему так, но наверно по принципу наибольшей простоты. Хотя формально ничто не мешает считать вторую часть самостоятельным предложением с опущенным подлежащим.
Наверное, тут есть элемент традиции, но с другой-то стороны, чего огород-то городить? Если предложение можно считать простым, зачем искать что-то еще? А сложносочиненным пусть оно будет тогда, когда по-другому не получается, то есть очевидно, что есть две пары главных членов.

Сравните: *В лесу растут грибы и ягоды*. Вряд ли кому придет в голову считать "ягоды" самостоятельным предложением (неполным) с опущенным сказуемым? Так чем ваш случай лучше?

Причинно-следственную связь тут в принципе можно разглядеть, но она никак не сказывается на подходе к грамматическому разбору.